# Printing unique elements in lines in a separate .txt file

Tags: python, file, bioinformatics

I have a huge input file i.e,

```
con1    P1  140 602
con1    P2  140 602
con2    P5  642 732
con3    P8  17  348
con3    P9  17  348
```

I want to iterate inside each con, remove repetitive elements in line[2] and line[3] and print the result in a new .txt file so that my output file looks like this,(Note: my second column might be different for each con)

```
con1    P1  140 602
con2    P5  642 732
con3    P8  17  348
```

My attempted script(not sure how to finish)

```
from collections import defaultdict
start = defaultdict(int)
end = defaultdict(int)
o1=open('result1.txt','w')
o2=open('result2.txt','w')
with open('example.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        start[line[2]]
        end[line[3]]
        if start.keys() == 1 and end.keys() ==1:
            o1.writelines(line)
        else:
            o2.write(line)
```

UPDATE: Additional example

```
con20   EMT20540    951 1580
con20   EMT14935    975 1655
con20   EMT24081    975 1655
con20   EMT19916    975 1652
con20   EMT23831    975 1655
con20   EMT19915    975 1652
con20   EMT09010    975 1649
con20   EMT29525    975 1655
con20   EMT19914    975 1652
con20   EMT19913    975 1652
con20   EMT23832    975 1652
con20   EMT09009    975 1637
con20   EMT16812    975 1649
```

Expected output,

```
con20   EMT20540    951 1580
con20   EMT14935    975 1655
con20   EMT19916    975 1652
con20   EMT09010    975 1649
con20   EMT09009    975 1637
```

Comment: Is the `(line[2], line[3])` pair unique for each con, or globally? That is, could you have `con1 P1 140 602` and `con2 P2 140 602`?

Comment: I need to have con1 p1 140 602 con1 p2 140 602 to be able to remove, so basically, line[2] and line[3] should have the same conx, while P can be different, so in the example you provided above, I cannot remove, since they have two different con..

Comment: @user3224522 What if you've a line `con4    P3  140 602` at the end?

Comment: I dont remove it, since it has different con from con1, basically lines 0,2,3 should be similar in order to remove

Comment: @user3224522 Please post a better example then, one that allowed repeated items for my code.

Comment: Here we go, I appended additional example to th equestion

Comment: @user3224522 And expected output? :)

Comment: since my file is huge, I might have >20 hits for each con, in this example I put only 1 con to see if the program is going to remove repetitives inside one con, cos what I need is to iterate inside each con and remove all elements that repeat in line[2],[3], then move to the next con, remove and so on

Comment: ok, updated, in other simple words, lines 0,2,3 should be identical, then I can remove, while I dont care if line 1 is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) here:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('input.txt') as f1, open('f_out', 'w') as f2:
    #Firstly group the data by the first column
    for k, g in groupby(f1, key=lambda x:x.split()[0]):
        # Now during the iteration over each group, we need to store only
        # those lines that have unique 3rd and 4th column. For that we can
        # use a `set()`, we store all the seen columns in the set as tuples and
        # ignore the repeated columns.   

        seen = set()
        for line in g:
            columns = tuple(line.rsplit(None, 2)[-2:])
            if columns not in seen:
                #The 3rd and 4th column were unique here, so
                # store this as seen column and also write it to the file.
                seen.add(columns)
                f2.write(line.rstrip() + '\n') 
                print line.rstrip()
```

**Output:**

```
con20   EMT20540    951 1580
con20   EMT14935    975 1655
con20   EMT19916    975 1652
con20   EMT09010    975 1649
con20   EMT09009    975 1637
```

Comment: I started my first attemp using groupby, but it doesnt remove all repetitives, I have checked your script on my bigger file, same issue..

Comment: would you mind to comment in this line, pls columns = tuple(line.rsplit(None, 2)[-2:])

Comment: @user3224522 I've added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**I said:**

```
f = open('example.txt','r').readlines()
array = []

for line in f:
  array.append(line.rstrip().split())


def func(array, j):
  offset = []
  if j < len(array):
    firstRow = array[j-1]
    for i in range(j, len(array)):
      if (firstRow[3] == array[i][3] and firstRow[2] == array[i][2]
        and firstRow[0] == array[i][0]):
        offset.append(i)

    for item in offset[::-1]:# Q. Why offset[::-1] and not offset?
      del array[item]

    return func(array, j=j+1)

func(array, 1)

for e in array:
  print '%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t%s' % (e[0],e[1],e[2],e[3])
```

**The box said:**

```
con20   EMT20540    951 1580
con20   EMT14935    975 1655
con20   EMT19916    975 1652
con20   EMT09010    975 1649
con20   EMT09009    975 1637
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do it as follows:

```
my_list = list(set(open(file_name, 'r')))
```

and then write that to your other file

#### Simple example

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,2]
>>> my_list = list(set(a))

>>> print my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Can you please explain what is wrong with my answer so that I can improve or remove it. Thank you

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it's because that would only remove lines that are completely unique. In his example, that would keep both the `P1` and `P2` lines.

Comment: @KirkStrauser, Why would it keep both the P1 lines? Aren't they the same string (even with the \n)? I don't understand. Thank you

Comment: Look at `['con1    P1  140 602', 'con1    P2  140 602']`. Those are duplicates according to the question (because "140 602" is the same in both) (if I'm reading this right), but would be distinct in your algorithm.

Comment: @KirkStrauser, It seems the OP changed his question after I posted the answer since earlier, the string were identical (even the P1)

Comment: No, I did not, the strings were different on purpose, to illustrate better